# Need help creating Back button in random generate photo gallery

Tags: javascript, html, random, numbers, solution

I made a image gallery that shows images randomly

Now I was only able to create a button for next but I need a back button also for the previous images

I used javascript for showing random images and now I can only generate next images. But i cannot create a back button for showing previously generated images
Please help
Thanks

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Image list</title>
<form name="imageForm">
  <table border=3>
   <tr align="center">
    <td>
      <input onclick="var temp = displayImage();displaynum(); return temp;"  type=button value="Click Here">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xBwug66.jpg" name="canvas" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script language="javascript">

var imagesArray = [
'http://i.imgur.com/aOBAdcS.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/f40kyc3.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/oM9MlZN.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/iCqIdVP.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/wfjPTaL.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/BInZqYM.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/SQAUhGN.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/zjzaS7C.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/y2qtX0G.jpg',
'http://i.imgur.com/dguKz5P.jpg',
];

var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;


function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    if (!usedImages[num]){
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
            usedImages = {};
        }
    } else {
        displayImage();
  displaynum();
    }
 

}



</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you consider using the browser back button? If so, you can change the hash (#) part of the URL for each image then the browser will remember the order for you.

Comment: thanks for the comment but sorry. I want a button that will display previously generated images

Comment: I am really a noob. can you show me how to change the hash ? i want to try

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you.
You have to have an array which keeps track of your history. Then pop the results out of it when you go backwards.

I've changed some of the function names so that way it's easier to tell what it is. I also removed displayNum() as you didn't have it in your source.

```js
var imagesArray = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/aOBAdcS.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/f40kyc3.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/oM9MlZN.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/iCqIdVP.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/wfjPTaL.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/BInZqYM.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/SQAUhGN.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/zjzaS7C.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/y2qtX0G.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/dguKz5P.jpg',
    ];

var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;
var numHistory = [];

function displayPreviousImage(){
    if (numHistory.length > 1){
      numHistory.pop();
      var num = numHistory[numHistory.length-1];
      document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    }
}

function displayNextImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    if (!usedImages[num]){
        numHistory.push(num);
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
            usedImages = {};
        }
    } else {
        displayNextImage();
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="imageForm">
  <table border="3">
   <tr align="center">
    <td>
      <input onclick="var tempPrev = displayPreviousImage(); return tempPrev;"  type=button value="Previous">           
      <input onclick="var tempNext = displayNextImage(); return tempNext;"  type=button value="Next">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xBwug66.jpg" name="canvas" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Of course! Glad that's what you needed. You may want to work a little bit on how you actually present the data. You can do it directly from the function. You only need to have onclick="displayPreviousImage()" etc.

Comment: Bro i got a bug in your code. i attached a counter to count how many images have been generated and detected the bug.the problem is If i press the back button it do not show all the images   https://jsfiddle.net/15pd2ptv/